# Find local maxima and minima of impulse train

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, maxima-minima

I have an impulse train given by

$$\sum_{j=0}^r \frac{\cos \bigl(\frac{2 \pi jx}{r+1} \bigr)}{r+1}$$

Plotted for $r=1$ (blue), $5$ (orange) and $8$ (green), this gives:

[image]

Ignore the case of $r=1$, as this is a simple $\cos$ curve.

Where, in terms of $x$, do the maxima and minima occur (in the given ranges), and what are their values in terms of $x$ and $r$?

Differentiation gives me

$$-\sum_{j=0}^r \frac{\frac{2 \pi j}{r+1}\sin \bigl(\frac{2 \pi jx}{r+1} \bigr)}{r+1}=0$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

**Edit:**

As per Yves' suggestion below, I tried to figure out the sum, but I hit a wall even before I get to differentiating:

$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{j=0}^r \frac{\cos \bigl(\frac{2 \pi jx}{r+1} \bigr)}{r+1}=\frac{1}{2(r+1)} \biggl(\sum_{j=0}^r e^{\frac{i2 \pi j x}{r+1}}+ \sum_{j=0}^r e^{\frac{-i2 \pi j x}{r+1}} \biggr)$$

Next,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} a^j=\frac{1-a^{r+1}}{1-a}$$

and setting $a=e^{\frac{i2 \pi x}{r+1}}$ (and therefore $a^{r+1}=e^{i2 \pi x}$), we have

$$\frac{1}{2(r+1)} \biggl(\sum_{j=0}^r e^{\frac{i2 \pi j x}{r+1}}+ \sum_{j=0}^r e^{\frac{-i2 \pi j x}{r+1}} \biggr)=\frac{1}{2(r+1)} \biggl(\frac{1-e^{i2 \pi x}}{1-e^{\frac{i2 \pi x}{r+1}}}+\frac{1-e^{-i2 \pi x}}{1-e^{\frac{-i2 \pi x}{r+1}}}\biggr)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2(r+1)} \biggl(\frac{\bigl(1-e^{i2 \pi x}\bigr)\bigl(1-e^{\frac{-i2 \pi x}{r+1}}\bigr)+\bigl(1-e^{\frac{i2 \pi x}{r+1}}\bigr)\bigl(1-e^{-i2 \pi x}\bigr)}{\bigl(1-e^{\frac{i2 \pi x}{r+1}}\bigr)\bigl(1-e^{\frac{-i2 \pi x}{r+1}}\bigr)}\biggr)$$

...but where do I go from there?

Comment: Hint: the sum $\sum_k cos k\theta$ has a closed-form expression.

Comment: Hi Yves. I know that $\sum_k \cos k\theta$ can be expressed as a telescoping complex geometric series (though sadly, I haven't yet figured out how...). But even if I knew the closed form expression, I'd still be at a loss.

Comment: Write it down before concluding.

Comment: Please see edited version of original question. I still get stuck, just earlier than before!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities. This will eventually lead you to a trigonometric equation with no closed-form solution, except for the small values of $r$ (up to four, presumably). You will have to use a numerical method.